# Checking for Roles & Permissions in zizaco/entrust laravel package

Tags: laravel

I'm using **zizaco/entrust** package in my laravel project beside multi Auth package name **Hesto/multi-auth**

Our project on laravel 5.4,

i get below error when i want to get current logged in users' role and permissions with this method:
`Entrust::hasRole('role-name');` OR `Auth::user()->hasRole('role-name');`

But I **can** access users' Role with this method for example :

```
$user = User::find($userid);
dd($user->hasRole('admin')); // Return true
```

i followed exactly installation instruction but i get below error :

```
`Non-static method Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust::hasRole() should not be called statically`
```

How can i solve my problem, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the `use` statement. Are you using the class or the `facade`? You want to be using the facade.

Comment: You might be using the wrong class. Have you tried to use `\Entrust::hasRole();`. Not yet tested, but the solution is that you need to use EntrustFacade mentioned over here : https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/EntrustFacade.php

Comment: @PaladiN it's work for me , and i had another problem in getting current logged in users in `vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/Entrust.php` in `user()` method. because im using `Hesto/MultiAuth` the previous return couldn't retrive current user ,Then for fix the problem , I changed return `$this->app->auth->user();` to return `Auth::guard('user')->user();` but i think still there is a problem with using Entrust Fecade

Answer (score 2):

In this error message you have answer to your problem:

> Non-static method Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust::hasRole() should not be called statically

You called this method `hasRole()` statically, but this method is non static. It means that you need to create object of this class, but you instead that used a class.

In the example that you gave:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
dd($user->hasRole('admin')); // Return true
```

you create an object of class `User`, and class `User` (I think) implements class `Entrust`:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
```

`$user` is an object and it`s not static, you can use hasRole().

In other words, to use method hasRole() (literally - is someone has a role?) you need this `someone`:

```
$user->hasRole('admin') // Is this user has role `admin`?
```

Hope, I explained it. Sorry about my English (I'm just studying).

Answer (score 0):

In your User.php file add EntrustUserTrait like

```
<?php

namespace App;

//...
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, EntrustUserTrait;

    //...
```